# Force deleting a record using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I've been designing a database for an online store where I have some tables related to products, retailers and orders. I've defined a trigger to prevent deleting an actual product, but instead, marking it as deleted since the product might be already sold and the customer might have made the payment. So if I actually delete the product, since the product id is referenced as foreign key in all other tables, serious problems in respect of losing orders, payment and financial data may happen in the system. Therefore I've done this:

```
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    DECLARE @id INT
    SELECT @id = ProductId FROM deleted d
    UPDATE Products SET Deleted = 1 WHERE ProductId = @id
BEGIN
    SET NoCount ON
END
```

But, this may increase the size of the table dramatically, and I want to provide the option for the database admin to actually get rid of the data when necessary. Since I've created this trigger, the record can't be physically removed normally. The reason why I did not define a Stored Procedure instead of this is that, this task is quite dangerous in this case  but however, I'm looking for a way to define a specific stored procedure to allow for getting rid of the whole data when necessary. I want to know if there is any way to force the record to be deleted despite having defined such trigger, using a stored procedure. I mean **by Overriding The Trigger** .

Comment: If you have foreign keys defined, then you won't be able to delete child records, unless you have on delete cascade. Also, you should be able to manage who can delete through `grant`ing permissions.

Comment: @Laurence: The other tables can be handled in the SP, but what about this one with this trigger. About permissions, I just wanna prevent accidents.

Comment: @Laurence: Then how about virtually deleting the record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option that you have to implement exactly what you are after is to develop a kind of password protected trigger (well not exactly password protected but something similar). This can be implemented (or hacked) using the `Context_Info()` function. The value it accepts is binary so you should cast your so called password to varbinary then. For example:

```
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    DECLARE @id INT
    SELECT @id = ProductId FROM deleted d
    DECLARE @Pass VARBINARY(MAX)
    SELECT @Pass = Context_Info()
    IF @Pass = CAST('MY Password' AS VARBINARY(MAX))
    BEGIN
       -- Delete All The Tables Where Product ID Has Been Defined As FK --
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
       UPDATE Products SET Deleted = 1 WHERE ProductId = @id
    END
BEGIN
    SET NoCount ON
END
```

To use the password you can do:

```
SET Context_Info CAST('MY Password' AS VARBINARY(MAX)) 
DELETE FROM Product WHERE ....
```

Comment: Thanks, this sound better than a separate stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

You should use foreign key constraints to enforce data integrity.

On a side note this trigger failed if more than one record was deleted. You should write this trigger something like ..

```
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Products
      SET Deleted = 1
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM deleted 
                  WHERE ProductId = Products.ProductId)
END
```

Also if you want to delete all the children records, just use a cascade delete. Which will delete any child records in referencing tables.

If for some reason you do not want to create foreign key constraints, or have cascade deletes, your only option is to revoke the `Delete` permissions on this table for all and then create a stored procedure and tell users to use that procedure for deleting records.

And in that procedure delete all the child records from all table referencing tables one by one and then finally delete from products table.

### Update

For admins who want to physically delete records, they can disable triggers and run delete commands, yes SQL Server has functionality of disabling trigger using the following command

```
DISABLE TRIGGER Tr_TriggerName ON dbo.Products;
GO
```

Comment: I wanna be able to both virtually delete the record by executing normal DELETE command while allowing for physically deleting the record and all its associated data using a stored procedure (something like by overriding this trigger). So does SQL Server have such capability that allow me to override my triggers when I need to ?

Comment: @PierreOverFlow yes you can diable trigger in sql server see my updated answer.

Comment: @M.Ali, how can the OP delete the record which has deleted value as 1, I was thinking, OP should not have the trigger and just update the column deleted when some one deltes the products from front end, another stored procedure can do regular delete after a certain period

Comment: One question, does this affect the way the trigger works in one instance or by running this the trigger remains disabled until re-enabled back again? If I need to enable the trigger again, then it's a bad move because of the concurrency control I have to implement then, many users may try to delete records at once so that will be a nightmare.